# Cannot push to github-pages

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Let's say I have a website on GitHub Pages. Let's call that website MyFirstSite. Now, I am trying to create a *new* website inside of a new repository. That website is called MyNewSite. After adding and committing the files for MyNewSite, I attempted to push the changes to the gh-pages branch, but received this response:

```
To http://github.com/Jaklabs/MyFirstSite
! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://github.com/Jaklabs/MyFirstSite'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

It's as if it's trying to push the files to my *other* repository instead of the one I'm trying to work with. I'm rather new to Git. There's probably a very simple solution to this, but could someone point it out for me?

Comment: What does `git remote -v` show?

Comment: You are definitely trying to push to the original repo. Either you are in the wrong directory, or your remotes are all mixed up

Comment: First try to git pull and then push again

Comment: "git remote -v" outputs `MyFirstSite https://github.com/L.C.J/MyFirstSite (fetch)` and `MyFirstSite https://github.com/L.C.J/MyFirstSite (push)`. Yes, there's definitely something wrong with the remotes, but how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
git push --force
```

if you are sure that you don't have any unsynced file in the remote. Just as a precaution, download or clone the repo's file to another location before using the above command.

If you have any unsynced work then use `git pull` before performing `git push` and resolve any merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Your remote is not configured properly, try removing your old remote URL by-

```
git remote rm MyFirstSite
```

and add a new remote by

`git remote add origin YOUR_REPO_URL`

you can get `YOUR_REPO_URL` from repo `clone or download` button on github.

run `git remote -v`,it should show something like `git@github.com:USERNAME/REPO_NAME.git`

Now, you can push your changes.